# SQL sort order in ilike "%s%" query

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I am working on a SQL query which gets the result from my table, and returns to the user.
Let's take the table name as demo. And it's columns as column1 and column2.
Let's say column1 is a string.

I have to perform a `column1 ilike "%<pattern>%"` in the SQL query.

It returns the results that contain pattern as substring in their column1 value. Simple till now.

Now the problem arises when I need to sort them. The specific sort order should be -

All the results that are `column1 ilike "<pattern>%"` should come before all the results that are
`column1 ilike "%<pattern>%"`. I am not able to figure out how to write this in SQL.

To give an **example** -

If my pattern is abc
and I have the following values in my DB -

`ddabcd1dd, dddabcd3ddd, xyz, dab, abcd, abcd1`

The result returned should be -
`abcd, abcd1, dab, ddabcd1dd, dddabcd3ddd`

I have tried Lavenstein distance as well, but that doesn't solve it, reason -

xabc comes before dab because xabc has lavenstein distance of 1 with abc and dab has a levenstein distance of 2. Can anyone help me out with this?

PS: I don't want to use Union operation. Elasticsearch is a great candidate, but I want to solve this using SQL. I am using postgreSQL.

Comment: `order by case when column1 ilike "<pattern>%" then 1 when column1 ilike "<%pattern>%" then 2 end`

Comment: Simply order by a `CASE when column1 ilike "<pattern>%" then 0 else 1 end` first

Comment: @JoshEller it worked :)
I don't know what I was thinking!

Answer (score 2):

You can `ORDER BY` whether the `column1` value is `ilike '<pattern>%'`, sorting descending so that values where the conditional is true sort first:

```
SELECT *
FROM data
WHERE column1 ilike '%abc%'
ORDER BY column1 ilike 'abc%' DESC, column1
```

Output (for your sample data):

```
column1
abcd
abcd1
ddabcd1dd
dddabcd3ddd
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=e1b72c5f48730f3104566b8962dc1a8d)

Comment: @SajalSharma I realised I made a typo in the description (although the code was OK); I've corrected that. Note in PostgreSQL you don't need a `CASE` expression,  you can sort on a boolean value directly.

Answer (score 1):

In order to sort the results, you need to add an ORDER BY clause, following your WHERE clause.

So your re-written SQL would look like this:

`SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE column1 ilike "%<pattern>%"
ORDER BY column1;`

[Source](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-order-by/)

Answer (score 0):

I came across question while working on a query myself. `ORDER BY POSITION('abc' IN LOWER(column1)), column1` solved for me.
Here is the solution I came up with:

```
SELECT column1, POSITION('abc' IN LOWER(column1)) as index
FROM data
WHERE column1 ilike '%abc%'
ORDER BY POSITION('abc' IN LOWER(column1)), column1;
```

To order by `'pattern%'` before `'%pattern%'`, I am assuming here you would like to order the rows with `<pattern>`'s index. So for values
`ddabcd1dd, dddabcd3ddd, xyz, dab, abcd, abcd1, xabc`, the order of the result will be:

```
column1, index
abcd, 0
abcd1, 0
xabc, 1
ddabcd1dd, 2
dddabcd3ddd, 3
```

The second order by `name` is to alphabetically order the results with the same index value.